# iOS 8 class dump fail

Tags: ios, xcode, reverse-engineering

Recently, the iOS8 SDK has been installed on my MAC mini with XCODE 6.0 IDE, and the SDK directory inside system is

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

All these frameworks operate well and my applications can implement them smoothly.

But how to class-dump them to get non public API from the result? The only result after class-dump 'Mach-O dynamically' file is always: **CDStructures.h**.
However, if I class-dump SDK 7, the result is generating many H-files for each framework.

So is there any method to get the 'class dump result' ? 
Or this procedure is forbidden by iOS 8 platform ?

Answer (score 0):

- My guess is that you have an older version of `class-dump`.  [Try getting a new one here](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/). This version works for me (iOS 8.2 and Yosemite).
- Another option is to run `class-dump` on the `iPhoneSimulator.platform` directory, instead of the `iPhoneOS.platform` directory:

  ```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/System/Library/
  ```
- You can also use `classdump-dyld` right on the device if it's jailbroken, as [described here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Reverse_Engineering_Tools).

### Reference

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Updating_extensions_for_iOS_8